# Turning off NLA (Network Level Authentication) locally with CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Is it possible to turn off the NLA using a batch file or through an elevated CMD?

Answer (score 5):

You can turn it off by manually editing the registry setting as shown below. You may have to restart the RDP service, but I didn't have to when I just tested this on a Win2k16:

`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-TCP" /v UserAuthentication /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f`

I recently had this come up during some pentesting labs where I had a remote shell on the machine but wanted to RDP in. It was relatively hard to find how to turn off NLA, as most articles address doing this remotely via PS-remoting or similar. I found this in my copy of the Red Team Field Manual ([https://www.amazon.com/Rtfm-Red-Team-Field-Manual/dp/1494295504](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1494295504)).

Hope this helps others with the same question.

Comment: Can confirm this worked on 2008 R2. Didn't even need to restart any services, it just worked immediately.